# why output of "=" differ from "<-" assignment operators?

Tags: r

```
> Roster=data.frame(
+   name=c('amit','jack','aman'),
+   age=c(23,31,44),
+   recived=c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)
+ )
> Roster(o/p)
  name age recived
1 amit  23    TRUE
2 jack  31   FALSE
3 aman  44   FALSE
> Roster=data.frame(
+   name<-c('amit','jack','aman'),
+   age<-c(23,31,44),
+   recived<-c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)
+ )
> Roster(o/p)
  name....c..amit....jack....aman.. age....c.23..31..44.
1                              amit                   23
2                              jack                   31
3                              aman                   44
  recived....c.TRUE..FALSE..FALSE.
1                             TRUE
2                            FALSE
3                            FALSE
```

R programing assignment difference.

Comment: Inside a function, argument names must always use `=`. The use of `<-` in that way creates objects in the patent environment but doesn't name them for the function call.

Comment: "parent environment" not "patent environment"